# Vertical line in thumb of range input

Tags: css

I am trying to create a line inside the thumb of a `<input>` with type [`range`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.range.html).

I have managed to modify some of the styling of the thumb using the `::-webkit-slider-thumb` pseduo-element selector, as shown below, but I need a vertical line centered in the thumb of the slider. Is there a way to create such a line?

```css
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance:none !important;
    width: 344px;
    height: 18px;
    /*background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 75%,#f6f6f6 75%,#f6f6f6 100%);*/
    /*-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2));*/
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background: rgb(190,220,0);
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance:none !important;
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(235,235,235,1) 100%, );
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2));
    z-index: 1;
    /*background: white url(../icons/gc4_icon_cssbutton-v.svg) no-repeat;*/
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="test" />
```

Comment: -1; the code you've posted is Webkit-only but the question doesn't seem Webkit-specific, and your code full of irrelevant stuff like commented out lines and transitions. This question would've been better if you'd provided a minimal example instead of a big code dump, and if you'd either made it specific to a particular browser or exhibited cross-browser code in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some old versions of Chrome *only* (but not in most browsers), you can do this using `::after` or `::before` pseudo-elements:

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    left:50%;
    width:1px;
    background:#000;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hrr5zacf/)

However, from Chrome 49 onwards, this [no longer works](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582301); allowing pseudo-elements to be chained in a CSS selector (like `foo::-webkit-slider-thumb::after`) was a violation of the CSS spec, and Chrome has changed its behaviour to conform to the spec. This also *never* worked in Firefox, Internet Explorer, or Edge.